# Replicating SQL data in real time from one DB to another

Tags: sql-server

I'm hoping for some opinions on the best options for how to replicate, in real time, data from a production SQL Server database onto another SQL instance.  This second instance would be for vendors who need to access some of the tables from the production database, but we would prefer that they not directly access our production instance.

I have some awareness of transactional replication and log shipping as possible solutions, but I would be interested in pros/cons of these approaches, or superior alternative solutions you may have tried.

I realize there are many topics already on Stack Overflow that discuss how to do this, but many that I found were older (technology's always changing), or focused on a very specific scenario.

Comment: Questions are often focused on a specific scenario because the advantages / disadvantages of different approaches can change depending on the details of the situation.

Comment: P.S. IMO log shipping is not very appropriate for real-time use because the shipped database is unavailable while the data transfer and restore is taking place. MS considers log shipping to be a business continuity feature rather than a data migration tool. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 . Lack of availability is generally not a problem with replication. Neither technology will provide totally real-time though - replication can be a few minutes behind as well, depending on implementation details etc.

Comment: More about replication here, for comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15 . You should read both the links I've posted, and the associated other pages, and draw your own conclusions based on your knowledge of the specific scenario, which will inevitably be superior to ours.

Answer (score 1):

For read-only access you can use AlwaysOn Availability Group feature introduced with SQL Server 2012

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15